# Como mostrar textos con formatos en negritas, cursiva, saltos de lineas o imagenes en un pdf

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

Yo tengo un editor en mi formulario de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es mostrar estos mismos formatos en un pdf, pero no me muestra los formatos! me los muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿cómo hago para mostrar los formatos en el pdf? por favor ayuda y muchas gracias de antemano!! esto usando dompdf, laravel y angularjs

la llamada con el dompdf lo hago asi:

```
    $data = $datos;
    $actividades = $actividades;
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $view = \View::make($vistaurl, compact('data', 'actividades', 'date'))->render();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);

    if($tipo==1){
        return $pdf->stream('reporte.pdf');
    }
    if($tipo==2){
        return $pdf->download('reporte.pdf');
    }
```

para mostrar lo hago asi:

```
<p>{{ $data->introduccion }}</p>
```

Comment: porfavooor ayuda :(